# spring boot loads yaml list as map

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I have a yaml file like this one

```
      framework:
              generalConfiguration:
                    cassandra:
                      fe:
                        seeds:
                            - fire201
                            - fire202
                        dc: DC
```

And a bean

```
public class ConfigurationBean{

private Map<String, Object> generalConfiguration;

public Map<String, Object> getGeneralConfiguration() {
    return generalConfiguration;
}

public void setGeneralConfiguration(Map<String, Object> generalConfiguration) {
    this.generalConfiguration = generalConfiguration;
}
```

A bean factory methods

```
@Bean(name = "configurationDataHolder")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "framework")
public ConfigurationBean configurationBean(){
    return new ConfigurationBean();
}
```

My problem is that spring boot populates the generalConfiguration Map where :
fe is a Map with keys

```
    seeds
    dc
```

dc is a String value entry.
and seeds is a map like this one:

```
0 -> fire201
1 -> fire202
```

I would expect seeds to be populated as a List.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: BTW, when I load this yaml with snakayaml it loads 'seeds' as a list as expected: new Yaml().load(fileName))

Answer (score 1):

Your `generalConfiguration` is using a raw type for the value so you're not giving any clue to the framework as what it is supposed to do with it. When you look at your configuration, it may be obvious to you but we process the configuration by browsing relationships one by one and taking the best possible options.

Your `Object` does not give any hint. Mixing simple values and maps in the same structure is also a smell.

Comment: Thank you @Stephane, I will change my structure.